# Предотвращение безмерного роста списка

Tags: python, panda3d, алгоритм, список

Вообще, чтобы устроить утечку памяти в python надо ещё постараться, но у меня это получилось!

Писал я змейку, и всё получалось неплохо ровно до того момента, когда я начал писать функцию, которая змею отображает. Со своими обязанностями функция справляется, правда, побочным результатом её работы является список, содержащий пустые узлы сцены, раздутый до монструозных размеров.

Код смотреть [здесь](https://github.com/canadien91/cobra/blob/master/main.py), особое внимание обратить на функцию `draw_snake`. При каждом вызове она удаляет все существующие узлы сцены и рисует новые (что уже не является самым эффективным алгоритмом, так как в большинстве случаев новые узлы появляются на месте старых).

Помогите исправить говнокод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Что такое "dot" (подсказка - ничего не говорящее название) и что это делает в классе Snale?
2. Сдвиг каждой части змеи может быть полезен, если каждая ее часть может быть чем-то уникальным (грубо - каждая часть разного цвета). В вашей же версии на данном этапе можно использовать оптимизированное перемещение - если встречаем dot, то координаты тела змеи не меняем, просто добавляем dot к змее. Если же dot не встречаем - просто переносим конец змеи в начало.
3. "get_score" я бы тоже вынес за пределы змеи - какое отношение имеет счет к змее-то?
4. не знаю панду, с питоном тоже слабо знаком, но вот вопрос - а в панде разве все вычисления/отрисовки выполняются в одном методе? А если вычисления будут значительными?
5. К тому же как в таком случае обработать следующую ситуацию:
6. есть две змеи,
7. скорость одной в два раза больше другой, т.е. одна змея за то же время должна пройти в два раза больше чем другая

Будете для каждой змеи использовать свой self.period? А если змей куча? Перенесете self.period в змеи? Или просто будете перемещать одних и тех же змей на разное расстояние? Тогда читай дальше:

- Одна из змей (та, которая должна перемещаться за один раз на расстояние большее в два раза, например, на две клетки) находится в точке [X, Y]
- В точке [X-1, Y] находится dot
- Змея перемещается в точку [X-2, Y]
- По логике, т.к. змея не должна "прыгать", то во время прохождения [X-1, Y] следующий dot может появиться в [X-2, Y], поэтому змея должна будет скушать и его - и все это за один ход (ведь у нас только один period)

И как вы это будете обрабатывать? Все-таки будете перемещать змею рывками? И генерировать dot уже после всех перемещений змеи? И че это за дергания такие будут?

Зачем отрисовывать и удалять объекты, если вы можете просто изменять координаты уже существующих?

```
obj.setPos( Point3( pos.getX( ), depth, pos.getY( ) ) )
```

Т.е. проходите по телу змеи, меняется аналогичные коры у briks, если тело закончено, а briks еще есть - тогда уже удаляете их, либо если наоборот - тело есть, а briks нет - добавляете.

Тоже несовсем оптимально, можно и получше придумать, но уже не тратитесь на лишнюю загрузку/удаление

Comment: @BOPOH, переписал, запушил пока в другую [ветку][1]. Вроде теперь утечек памяти нет, но говнокодом всё равно попахивает.

[1]:https://github.com/canadien91/cobra/blob/drawing/main.py

Answer (score 0):

Это не утечка памяти; утечка памяти - это когда память отведена, но ссылок на эту переменную не осталось, поэтому явно память обратно не освободить.
Я не знаю, на каком фв это делается, но по идее у вас фиксированное количество блоков, которые могут принадлежать змее, еде или полю - их не надо перерисовывать вообще, только менять цвет, в крайнем случае накладывать слой змеи (опять фиксированное и предрассчитываемое количество точек) на бекграунд.

и что мешает сделать self.bricks = [] после удаления старой сцены?

Comment: Фреймворк Panda3D. В принципе, я уже так и сделал, но ощущение того, что это говнокод не пропало...

Comment: @Fike, согласно [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8) здесь именно утечка:

    if self.bricks:
        for brick in self.bricks:
            brick.removeNode( )

Не знаю что делает removeNode, но самое главное - brick из self.bricks не удаляется, хотя он уже не нужен. В итоге ненужные объекты накапливаются, постепенно съедая всю память.